# How Do I root Motorola x Force?

Tags: rooting, motorola

I've just bought a shiny new Motorola X Force and I would like to be able to root it.

Is there an app that I can use?

https://www.motorola.co.uk/products/moto-x-force

Any help  would be much appreceated

Answer (score 2):

Good that you got the X Force instead of Droid Turbo 2 (Verizon's variant), that means your device is eligible for unlocking the bootloader and thus rooting relatively easily.

- Unlock bootloader following [here](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/standalone/bootloader/unlock-your-device-a) - all data including internal storage will be wiped, so be sure to back up.
- Flash TWRP recovery [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/droid-turbo-2/development/recovery-t3306253).
- Flash a suitable SuperSU package in TWRP. Use ["systemless"](https://download.chainfire.eu/969/SuperSU/UPDATE-SuperSU-v2.76-20160630161323.zip) if you want to keep the system intact so you *theoretically* would be able to take OTA updates, or use ["system mode"](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/supersu/v2-64-2-66-supersu-mode-t3286120) if you want root to persist across factory resets.
- Optionally, flash CyanogenMod 12.1 [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/droid-turbo-2/development/rom-cm-12-1-kinzie-t3319189) in case you're bored with Moto's UI and want it replaced altogether. You lose stuffs like Moto Assist though.